# Retaining the instance state of Fragments in Fragment Pager Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a frustrating problem. I'm able to create each fragment that the pager adapter handles, and I'm able to swipe-right to view all of them; however, upon swiping left, the fragments are either gone or just duplicates of the one I was already looking at. I googled around, and couldn't find much, which is confusing as the API for the FragmentPagerAdapter says that it keeps each fragment in memory. I'll be displaying a max of like 20 fragments, so memory isn't an issue. Anyway, here's my code, and I appreciate any feedback you can give; it's still in like pre-alpha stage.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_screen);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new         SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

 /**
  * TEMPORARY
  */
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.events_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return EventFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    /**
     * Total number of pages (fragments) there are
     * Given by size of the array returned by Service.getEvents()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return connection.getEvents().size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * The fragment holding the text for each event.
 */
public static class EventFragment extends Fragment {

    static int index;

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static EventFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        index = sectionNumber;
        EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events_screen, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(connection.getEvents().get(index - 1));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right fragments are kept in memory but it will used large amount of memory thus giving not expected result you want as the documentation is saying:

> The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state. For larger sets of pages, consider FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

The [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) is the one you are looking for if you want to have a lot of page/fragments in the adapter.

Comment: Does ~15-20 count as a lot of page/ fragments? All it's showing is some text. I doubt this is a memory-hog.

Comment: Right, I'll look into your link then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Upon using the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, I was able to fix two problems:

1) Duplicate fragments that frustratingly disappeared when I swiped right and left. This was due to getItem() calling twice for the same fragment due to EventFragment.newInstance(position + 1).

2) Save the instance state of fragments so that I could continually swipe left and right without coming upon a blank page.

Thanks for your help, @Rod_Algonquin. Saved me hours of stress.